# NPM ERR code FETCH_ERROR npm install firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, installation, nom

i have problem npm install firebase

npm install --save firebase
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase%2ffirestore reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dell/.npm/_logs/2021-09-08T08_05_33_702Z-debug.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this url is valid and have return response , please change your dns or change your IP with VPN and try again